# when running nodejs angular app in docker it is returning failed

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am trying to setup poc for docker with one simple project. It includes angular, express, nodejs and mongodb atlas.

angular runs on 4200 and nodejs 3000

https://github.com/changan1111/UserManagement

it is working fine in local the same setup..

When I go for docker?

I am seeing that node js is started and running.

[image]

When I see the list of files, I am seeing all good.

[image]

[image]

When I go for http://localhsot/user it returns values

[image]

But when I read the value from browser it is showing

[image]

[image]

i have tried few solutions which is given but all returns same response that failed. what is wrong with this.. can any one look in to this and let me know that what is the problem on the setup.

```
app.use(cors());

/*
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "req.headers.origin"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,PUT,GET,POST");

  next();
});*/


/*
app.use(cors({
  "origin": ['http://localhost:3000'],
  "methods": "GET,PUT,POST",
  "preflightContinue": false,
   "credentials": true
}));*/
```

tried with ip address http://192.168.0.103/ as well but no change
Dockerfile:

[image]

Comment: Firstly you have to put EXPOSE before CMD in your Dockerfile

Comment: that is copy paste error while taking.. EXPOSE was given before CMD

Comment: Please replace images of code with real code.

Comment: In your browser you're calling `localhost:3000/user` and not `localhost/user`. And your problem is, that your app somehow is reachable on `80` instead of `3000`?

Comment: Is your mapped port (the one that you can try to hit from outside) matching the exposed one? Usually you would want to specify the port when running a container with some ports exposed in it.

Comment: P.S. Your Angualr isn't supposed to be running on any port. It should be built and served with a static server such as nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear in your question but, according to the images you provided, if seems that your Angular app is unable to reach your Express backend in `127.0.0.1`.

You configured `http://localhost:3000` as your API endpoint, but please, be aware that from the point of view of Docker `localhost` refers to the container itself, and could be not the same as your actual host.

To solve the problem, you could indicate to `Express` that it should [listen](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) in every network interface using `0.0.0.0`:

```js
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("listening on PORT verify: 3000");
});
```

The solution is exemplified in the [nodejs guide documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) as well.

In addition, please, try adjusting the `Url` variable in your `environment` files to the address `http://localhost`, without indicating the port, i.e., using port `80`: according to the code you uploaded to your repository in Github your app seems to listen on port `3000`, but in your screenshots you are certainly using port `80`. The reasoning behind this is that if `express` is serving both your Angular SPA and your API, and you are able to contact both things from your host, using `http://localhost/read` and `http://localhost/user`, respectively, then probably adjusting you `Url` variable to `http://localhost` as advised could do the trick.

Comment: I changed app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log("listening on PORT verify: 3000");
});
But still i did not see any difference in behavior

Comment: CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND         CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                  NAMES
731365201d70   106d      "node server"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp   cranky_pasteur    I have tried localhost and used ip from the hosts in browser (# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.0.106 host.docker.internal
192.168.0.106 gateway.docker.internal)

Comment: Can u pls let me know any other details needed?

Comment: Hi @ChanGan. I am sorry to hear that it didn't work properly. Are you still facing the same issue? Exactly the same problem? As you are serving with Express both the Angular output and the API, you could try using relative routes in your `apiservice.service`. I mean, the env variable `Url` could be defined as an empty string in your environment. Perhaps this alternative approach could be of help. Ideally, your SPA should be serve by some kind of web server, like nginx. This server will probably proxy the requests issued against your API. I am uncertain about the use of Express for this purpose

Comment: initially i tried url: "/"  to take it base url from the origin.. but this is serving empty in the request.. http:///user .. the origin is not getting added in the request. but it should go as http://{requestedip}/user..  since that is empty going 3 slashes

Comment: @ChanGan I updated the answer with further ideas. I hope they be of help.

Comment: Did the same change and working fine.. accepting that answer

Comment: That is great @ChanGan. I am happy to hear that the proposed solution worked properly and you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try exposing your ports like this when running your container?

`docker run -p 4000:4000 container_name` (assuming Linux host here)

or just

`docker run --network="host" container_name` perhaps?

Then access via `localhost:4000` from any service inside or outside Docker.

The container's internal `localhost` will match up with your actual host machine's `localhost` this way.
There are some downsides to this, but I'm assuming you're not running this in a production setting, so it shouldn't really matter much.

It isn't clear whether you're trying to access your Dockerized app from outside Docker. Are both your backend and frontend sharing the same container? Are they both containerized?

`EXPOSE` only allows Docker's internal apps to find that port IIRC.

You need to specify ports to expose to your host.

Comment: He has exposed the ports via docker-compose.

Comment: @akop My bad. Must have missed that, didn't dig into the repo much yet. The previous answer mentioned confusion between host and container `locahost` ports being a potential issue, so I figured matching them up exactly might reduce chances of mixups there (if the OP didn't do it already).